# Package.json dependencies and reducing time for step Generating es5 bundles for differential loading

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, tsconfig

I need some clarification here: If your application's package.json has **dependencyA** and another **commonDependency**, and commonDependency's package.json already has **dependencyA**, does your application need **dependencyA** in its package.json? My guess is no, but I need to confirm.

I am trying to reduce the time (currently ~60 mins on our Jenkins server) it takes for this step: Generating es5 bundles for differential loading...

I believe by removing some of these "peer/nested" dependencies from our application, the build times will improve.

**Application Package JSON**

```
"dependencies": {
   "@dependencyA": "1.2.3", <-- is this required here?
   "@commonDependency": "2.3.4"
}
```

**CommonDependency Package JSON**

```
"dependencies": {
   "@dependencyA": "1.2.3",
   "@dependencyB": "4.5.6",
   "@dependencyC": "7.8.9",
}
```

**Application TSConfig JSON**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "./node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    },
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
My issue now is this:
In the Application, there are .ts files that have
`import ... from @dependencyA`.

So when I remove the dependencyA from Application package.json, the ng build fails.

It will not resolve
`import ... from @commonDependency`, which has dependencyA in its package.json. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you also need the direct dependency if you rely on it. Why? Because the transitive dependency may become incompatible or be removed entirely (your dependency may stop using that package)

Comment: Thanks.  I am going to try removing the packages one by one from the Application and build it. We have devDependencies and peerDependencies and I won't alter those for now.